Are my inequality steps legal?
To prove a certain statement by induction: $5^{n}$+$9$<$6^n$ , for each integer $n>=2$, I've assumed the hypothesis:

$5^{k}$+$9$<$6^k$

To prove:$5^{k+1}+9<6^{k+1}$
I've solved the inequation in the following way:

$5(5^k+9)<(6^k)6$ $[5<6]$
$5^{k+1}+45<6^{k+1}$
$\therefore$ $5^{k+1}+9<6^{k+1}$$[9<45]$

Is this legal since I've not multiplied by the same values on both sides?

Yes, your proof is correct.  You have used the fact that $0<a<b, 0<c<d$ implies that $ac <bd$ which is true, but may require a proof depending on at what stage you are in. It is perhaps better to write $ac <bc <bd$.

You also need the basic step, that the result is true for $n=2$. You also could use $9<(5+1)^n-5^n$ with the binomial formula.

The first line might need a little bit more.  You can’t always multiply inequalities, for instance, consider $-2<1$ and $-2<-1$.

It's not illegal anywhere to write incorrect mathematics so yes they're legal. :) But I'm quite sure that everyone would agree th$a$t the way you're using M$a$t$h$Ja$x$ is illegal. :/

@Nothingspecial what the hell do you mean by that?

Yes, it's fine. You can add an intermediate step if you are unsure;
$$\begin{gathered}
5^k+9 < 6^k \\
5(5^k+9) < 5(6^k) \text{ and } 5(6^k) < 6(6^k) \\
5(5^k+9) < 6(6^k) \\
\vdots
\end{gathered}
$$
Hope it helps.

yes it does, thanks a lot.

You also can use a different proof method, namely a direct proof using the binomial formula. Since $n\ge 2$, we have
$$
6^n-5^n=(5+1)^n-5^n > \binom{n}{1}5^{n-1}\ge \binom{2}{1}5=10>9.
$$
